# Is there any way to control scroll bar using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, browser-scrollbars

In my below code a function to scroll DIV for every set of intervals where when I try to scroll up due to interval refresh scroll bar again coming down.

My code:

```
   var int = self.setInterval("f2()", 1000);
   function f2() {
   var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages2");
   objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
   }
```

Now, by using `onscroll` property for DIV is there anyway to stop scrolling down when holding scroll bar with mouse?

Something like

```
       var int = self.setInterval("f2()", 1000);
       function f2() {
       var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages2");
       // if(objDiv.onscroll) i.e. when the particular DIV's scroll bar is on hold by cursor.
          {
          return false;
          }
       else
          {
            objDiv.scrollTop = objDiv.scrollHeight;
          }
      }
```

If the above kind of function can be implemented anybody please correct its syntax. I am a newbie to JavaScript.

Thanks in advance..!

Answer (score 6):

I’m not sure what you are asking here, but `window` has a scroll event that you can listen to, and so does any other element that has `overflow: auto|scroll` set using CSS.

You can’t prevent the default scrolling behavior, but you can use the `scrollTo()` method or the `scrollTop` property if you want to do something annoying like:

```
window.onscroll = function() {
    window.scrollTo(0,0);
};
```

Here is a nice compat table of the scroll event: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/scroll.html

`scrollTo()` docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Window.scrollTo

Comment: Is it not possible for DIV layer with `overflow:auto` ?

Comment: Yes it is, any element that has ``overflow`` set to ``auto`` or ``scroll``.

Comment: I am sorry it didn't work. I tried as `var objDiv = document.getElementById("messages2");
       objDiv.onscroll = function () {
           objDiv.scrollTo(0, 0);
       };` If you don't mind can you please provide me the syntax for my div?

Comment: The ``scrollTo()`` is only available on the window object, if you want to do the same for a HTML element, try ``scrollTop = 0;`` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/an8Gd/